# notifyDataSetChanged mess up my list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to use `notifyDataSetChanged` , to update my list view in order to change one row in it from password dots, to plain text and back to password dots.

In my adapter (changed it based on a comment here ) I check the type of the object that I have in that row. If the row is a password I set it to

```
setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

in order to turn the password text to dots. Later in my activity a click on that row will change it type to "notPass", and I am trying to refresh my listview with `notifyDataSetChanged` to represent it as a visible text.

```
public class UserAccountAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserAccountData> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    UserAccountData data[] = null;
    TreeSet<String> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<String>();

    public UserAccountAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            UserAccountData[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserAccountDataHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new UserAccountDataHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgUserAccountIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);


            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserAccountDataHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        UserAccountData userAccountData = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(userAccountData.title); 
        //hold

er.txtTitle.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(userAccountData.icon);
        if(userAccountData.type.equals("pass")){

            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        }
        else{
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTransformationMethod(null);
        }


        return row;
    }

    static class UserAccountDataHolder {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
    }
```

The object that I am giving the adapter is:

```
public class UserAccountData {
    public int icon;
    public String type;
    public String title;
    public UserAccountData(){
        super();
    }

    public UserAccountData(int icon, String title, String type) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

And my activity part that deals with the clickListener is:

```
 usersArray = new UserAccountData[user_data.size()];
 user_data.toArray(usersArray);

 final UserAccountAdapter adapter = new UserAccountAdapter(this,
                                        R.layout.user_accounts_row, usersArray);

 userAccountsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userAccounts);
 userAccountsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

 userAccountsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if(adapter.getItem(position).type.equals("pass")){
                adapter.getItem(position).setType("notPass");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
            else if(adapter.getItem(position).type.equals("notPass")){
                adapter.getItem(position).setType("pass");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

Right now when I am clicking on a password field with dots, that field remains dotted and some but not all of the other fields that are of type user/email/phone are also turning into dots

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: solved the issue. 
1) needed an else if, and not if / if.
2) changed the adapter based on one of the comments

Comment: you have an arrayadapter. why do you keep a reference to data in your class, when you could use getItem ?

Comment: That would be better, but this would not solve my problem. Updated my post to reflect the changes I did based on your comment

Comment: i know, that's why it is a comment, not an answer. did you check that getView is called for your item after the setType ?

Comment: Yes It is called. I also checked that that type of the item at the position changed.

Comment: and calling setTransformationMethod(null) doesn't do anything ? since the text doesn't change, may be you need to invalidate the view ?

Comment: also, you should be using PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()

Comment: changed to getInstance. and setTransformationMethod(null) does not do anything. The current state is that the password row's type is changed to notPass, all of the other fields have dots instead of text. and re-clicking on the password field does not change anything

Comment: did you try to put another transformationmethod to see if it does anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter class in the getView Method you don't reset the transformation for fields with type 'no pass'.

```
if(userAccountData.type.equals("notPass")){
        holder.txtTitle.setTransformationMethod(null);
    }
```

Instead of directly using the position as an array index, you could get the associated data with the 'getItemAtPositionMethod'

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        UserAccountData uad = (UserAccountData)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //your code

        });
```

Try to set values directly in each getView call:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserAccountDataHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    UserAccountData userAccountData = data[position];
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    if(userAccountData.type.equals("pass")){
        tvTitle.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
    }

    if(userAccountData.type.equals("notPass")){
        tvTitle .setTransformationMethod(null);
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Hey faceman, thanks for trying to help, but the issue is still not resolved. I got my uad and called setType on it , but for some reason the password field is still cover with dots and all the other fields are also being cover with dots.

Comment: ok, can you try it without the UserAcountDataHolder? access the textfields directly and don't cache them... Android recycles the list item views. Example: `code` ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

Comment: Hey I am a bit confused , what does row stand for in my code?

Comment: the actual view int the 'getView' method

Comment: same issue, the password row remains dotted , and any other field is also turned into a dotted field. re-clicking on the password field just keeps everything doted as well